# Update Query in Yii using Command Create not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I am trying to update a table from Yii Framework, but getting error

My code is as below:

```
$updatebrick = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("update link_bricks SET parent_id=". $v[parent_id] ." where child_id=". $k[micro_brick_id] ." ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1")->queryAll();
```

Error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error. The SQL statement executed was: update link_bricks SET parent_id=1963 where child_id=15793 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi ORDER BY and LIMIT are allowed in an UPDATE see [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Comment: It works fine when executing directly from phpmyadmin

Comment: instead of ->queryAll(); use ->query();

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi Nope; use `execute`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `execute` function instead of `queryAll`. `queryAll` is for SQL (`SELECT` statements) and `execute` is for DML (`UPDATE`,`INSERT`,`DELETE` statements).
See [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand).

You should also consider binding the parameters in using the framework, rather than injecting them (for security and sanity reasons).

I would suggest:

```
$sql='
  UPDATE link_bricks 
  SET parent_id=:parent_id 
  WHERE child_id=:child_id 
  ORDER BY id ASC
  LIMIT 1
';

$command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$update=$command->execute(array(
  'parent_id'=>$v[parent_id],
  'child_id'=>$k[child_id],
);
```

Comment: @Himanshu No problem, happy to help. If you could you accept the answer that'd be peachy!

Comment: opps, sorry :) I would do up vote as well, but don't have that much of reputation here